# Using i18n translated titles as a route in symfony

Tags: symfony1

I am trying to route some categories based on their translated names, not working so far,

My model is good, the category name is translated, the link is done properly in the good language, but, all categories are pointing at the same page(one of the category).

so /category/toys, would go at the same page than /category/clothing, same from the french names like /category/jouet,

this was working before I added i18n on the cats name,

anyone has an idea?

```
view_categorie:
  url:   /categorie/:name/
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: csw_Categorie, type: object }
  param: { module: categorie, action: listing }
```

Comment: if you remove the i18n on cats works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the following ideea : 
/categorie/:id/:name.html

In this way you don't depend on the name for the category selection, but on the id, and you can use the name as a SEO aid for your webpage.